# custom pagination to table using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I'm trying to add pagination for my code. I'm able to add number of rows after clicking 
    add button. But, getting confused how to apply pagination custom.

Any advice on how to implement? 
This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/H2ps5/185/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
$scope.firstname = 'Nizam'; // Set First Name on Page Load.
$scope.lastname = 'Ali'; // Set Last Name on Page Load.
$scope.users = []; // Define "users" Array.

/**
 * Adding a new user.
 */
$scope.newuser = function(){

    if($scope.firstname != "" && $scope.lastname != ""){ // If Values are not Empty.
        this.users.push( // Push the values of First Name & Last Name in "users" Array.
            {
                firstname:$scope.firstname, // Key value pair.
                lastname:$scope.lastname
            }
        );
        $scope.firstname = ''; // Clear First Name
        $scope.lastname = ''; // Clear Last Name
    } else {
        alert("Please fill values");
    }
}

$scope.remove = function(user){ // Removing the user.
    $scope.users.splice($scope.users.indexOf(user),1);
}
```

});

Kindly give me suggestions in which way I need to go

Comment: Hope it helps you.. http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/1050/

Comment: @Gaurav, I've already seen that. It's very confusing for me as a new bie. And my scenario is such that I will be adding a row dynamically. Thanks Yaar.

Answer (score 0):

Diretive should be a way.

Make your own directive to handle how to manipulate the DOM when number of users in the scope gets to 10 or 20 or whatever you want.

Maybe another one for nav links between pages.